# How To Sum a Column If Another Column Have Some Text String Within Date Range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a bank account statement and I wanted to sum specific types of transactions of every month

Column B has dates and Column C has transactions description and I wanted to sum Column E only transactions which have P2M and NBSM Types of transaction

This is the formula that I used but This formula sums only 1st searched text string not 2nd

`=SUMIFS(E:E, B:B, ">=01/09/2023", B:B, "<=30/09/2023", C:C, {"*P2M*","*NBSM/*"})`

This is the
[Google Sheet Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukKul.png)

Comment: @BartMcEndree I also tried this but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may test:*

```js
=arrayformula(sumifs(E:E, eomonth(B:B,),"=30-Sep-2023", --regexmatch(C:C,"P2M|NBSM"),1))
```

Comment: Now It's Working for Sep How To Make It Working For Other Months

Comment: use your own version `B:B, ">=01/09/2023", B:B, "<=30/09/2023"` ***OR*** use the last date of the month here `eomonth(B:B,),"=30-Sep-2023"`